# Inline keywords in LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice-writer, keyword

In drafting legal documents, in many cases, key words are defined in a particular section, and reused throughout the document. What would be useful and may already exist, is a way of keeping track of those key words and definitions. Such things may be when the keyword is changed or spell corrected, all instances are corrected; keyword highlighting; a hover box by the mouse pointer over a usage of the definition.

Does this exist in fields, for instance?

Comment: What has your research told you?

Comment: https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/images/6/6d/0214WG3-WorkingWithFields.pdf

Comment: @DavidPostill I am somewhat familiar with fields, but I can't find something exactly where there there can be a large number of fields, where both the field name and field value can both be any text and displayed in the document